# Filling out a batch of pdfs using .txt on acrobat

Tags: javascript, excel, adobe, acrobat

I keep getting the error cannot open file. I have made this work on mac only. It is supposed to go through lines of the .txt file and fill out the pdf then save as the names. It saves loads of time as there are 70+ pdf's I need to save. I have tried changing the "/" for the path to "" but that returns syntax error: unterminated string literal. It is asking me to add more details to post this so I will just add more words until it goes away.

```
   // specify the filename of the data file
var fileName = "/Users/rgivens/Documents/Courseware Audit Report.txt";     
    // the tab delimited text file containing the data
var outputDir = "/Users/rgivens/Desktop/Grade Change Form/";    // make sure this ends with a '/'

var err = 0;
var idx = 0;
while (err == 0) {
    err = this.importTextData(fileName, idx); // imports the next record
    if (err == -1) app.alert("Error: Cannot Open File"); 
    else if (err == -2) 
        app.alert("Error: Cannot Load Data"); 
    // else if (err == -3) 
        // We are not reporting this error because it does 
        // indicate the end of our data table: We've exhausted 
        // all rows in the data file and therefore are done with 
        // processing the file. Time to exit this loop. 
        // app.alert("Error: Invalid Row"); 
    else if (err == 1) 
        app.alert("Warning: User Cancelled File Select"); 
    else if (err == 2) 
        app.alert("Warning: User Cancelled Row Select"); 
    else if (err == 3) 
        app.alert("Warning: Missing Data"); 
    else if (err == 0) { 
        this.saveAs(outputDir + this.getField("Stu Name").value + "_" + this.getField("Stu Name 1").value + ".pdf"); // saves the file idx++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running this script? From the Console? If so, you should get a line number information.

Comment: The path was wrong I should have /c/ at the beginning, thanks though.